# How do I stop MediaPlayer sound while the App is closed/minimized?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-button

In my stopwatch app, the start button is supposed to start sound and the Pause button is supposed to stop the sound. Upto this scenerio, my program works fine.

But during playing the sound, if I go back or minimize the app , the sound doesn't stop. It keeps playing (all the time, even the device is idle). And the strange thing is that when I reopen the app to stop the sound it never gets stopped.
How to solve this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

               mp.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);


        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.pause();

            }
       }
    });
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);


    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            timerValue.setText("" + 00 + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", 00) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", 00));
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            timeSwapBuff = 0;

        }
    });

}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Android lifecycle.

I think you can call `mp.pause();` on `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

sample code:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.pause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should access the same MediaPlayer object
make it public, maybe works
this solution worked for me: create a class and define static MediaPlayer object and static methods(pause,stop,etc)
also you can override onPause method in activity class and stop mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

To stop playing, call `mp.pause()` right on the `onPause()` function. However, your *onStop()* should look more like:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();        //  <<-------ENSURE onStop()
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
```

If you have a MENU and HOME button in your device, you should check that your app recovers after pressing those buttons as well.

Kf